# Batch file timer

Tags: batch-file, timer

I would like to know I there is any way to make a timer in a batch file where you press something and it does something and if you don't it does something else

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but without a clue as to the operating system and batch processor it is impossible to advise further.

Answer (score 1):

```
CHOICE /C ABCDN /N /T 10 /D C /M "CHOICE A, B, C, D or None?"
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 SET val=A
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 SET val=B
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 SET val=C
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 SET val=D
IF ERRORLEVEL 5 SET val=None
@ECHO You chose %val%
```